# Calculate a moving average from circular data in r

Tags: r, moving-average, arima

I want to calculate a mean angle in radians (theta) from a series of angles (beta), which are stored in a dataframe called 'a':

```
       time beta    theta           theta2
    1   0           na              na
    2   2.426551575 na              na 
    3   5.890842799 0.678069689     0.678069689
    4   0.530641823 0.854950297     0.854950297
    5   4.794960386 -0.449975202    5.833210105
    6   1.271620156 0.104679019     0.104679019
    7   5.789548201 -0.236747291    6.046438017
    8   1.053579352 0.610520801     0.610520801
    9   0.095112206 0.218351484     0.218351484
    10  6.108843722 0.324783324     0.324783324
```

the betas are in radians and are generated as a random draw from the wrapped gauchy distribution.  I want to calculate thetas (actually theta2, in radians).   I did these by brute force, converting radians into positive and negative units with pi/-pi at 180 degrees, but was looking for a more elegant approach.

I had hoped that this would work (invoking both circular and dplyr packages):

```
a$theta<-mean.circular(c(a$beta,lag(a$beta),lag(a$beta,2))
```

But this only seems to return the last value of beta.  I've tried subsetting and also within a loop (I have another field called time that is an incrementing integer)

```
    time    beta
    1   0
    2   2.426551575
    3   5.890842799
    4   0.530641823
    5   4.794960386
    6   1.271620156
    7   5.789548201
    8   1.053579352
    9   0.095112206
   10   6.108843722



theta<-0
bset<-c(0,0,0)
for (i in time){
  bset<-ifelse(i<3,bset,df$beta[(i-2):i])
  thetai<-mean.circular(bset)
  theta<-c(theta,ifelse(is.na(thetai),0,thetai))

theta<-theta[2:(length(time)+1)]
df<-cbind(df,theta)
}
```

But this also is not working.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

I believe if I understood you correctly then you are trying to calculate moving averages of data which is circular in nature. If that is the case,  You may choose raster's `movingFun` function to get the moving averages. Since mean is not vectorized in nature, it will always return one value.

It would be good if you paste your desired output.

Here, I choose a value of lag as 2 and circular nature as True.

```
library(raster)
movingFun(x, n= 2, fun = mean, circular = TRUE)
```

**Input data:**

```
x <- c(0,2.426551575,
       5.890842799,
       0.530641823,
       4.794960386,
       1.271620156,
       5.789548201,
       1.053579352,
       0.095112206,
       6.108843722,
       1.240271853,
       5.350922943)
```

**Output**:

```
> movingFun(x, n= 2, fun = mean, circular = T)
 [1] 2.6754615 1.2132758 4.1586972 3.2107423
 [5] 2.6628011 3.0332903 3.5305842 3.4215638
 [9] 0.5743458 3.1019780 3.6745578 3.2955974
```

Comment: Thank you--this is helpful.  Yes, the data are circular (they are in radians).  movingFun() seems to use the actual data to derive the boundaries of the circle...is there a way to force this to 0 and 2pi?

Comment: @TCS, are you talking about scaling your mean values, if that is so, you can do: `NISTunits::NISTradianTOdeg(scales::rescale(vect, to=c(0,2*pi)))` , here "vect" is your output of `movingFun`, you have to pass it function called rescale from scales library, Incase you want to convert to degress then you can use NISTunits library.